# MySQL keep crashing

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

It was working fine yesterday but now mysql stops suddenly for unknown reason.

I tried to include this in the my.ini file under [mysql]
    innodb_force_recovery=1
but it did not have any effect.

mysql_error.log

```
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 3937615; transaction id 2345
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-08-08  9:39:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190808  9:39:45
```

Error showing on Xampp:

```
9:39:44 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
9:39:45 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
9:40:01 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
9:40:01 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
9:40:01 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:40:01 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:40:01 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:40:01 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:40:01 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
9:40:01 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
9:40:01 AM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

As per logs firewall or antivirus is blocking the MySQL ports. Try to allow ports of firewall and also add expectations on firewall and check at your end.

Comment: Xampp was running on administrator mode and yet firewall was blocking it? Well, I did what you suggested I allowed port 3306 through the firewall both Inbound/Outbound, yet I am getting the same error.